# Having an issue with an array

Tags: php

I have a query that returns rows that have an ID, and coordinates (X,Y) and an array of specific ID's. What I am trying to do is get the coordinates of the specific ID's and pass them to a new array. It works for the first item in my array but will not pull the subsequent ones.

Code below:

```
$AllPoints = $pdo->prepare($sqlAllPoints);
    $AllPoints->execute();
    $wpArray = array();
    $i = 1;
    while($apRow = $AllPoints->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //WHY TF IS THIS NOT WORKING PAST 1??
    {
        for($i = 1; $apRow['UID'] == $optRoute[$i]; $i++)
        {
            echo("<br/>UID: " . $apRow['UID'] . " | UID2: " . $optRoute[$i] . "<br/>");
            $wpCoor = $apRow['Y'] . ", " . $apRow['X'];
            array_push($wpArray,$wpCoor);
        }
    }

    echo("<br/> wpArray: ");
    print_r($wpArray);
    echo("<br/>" . $i);
```

and it returns:

> Array ( [0] => Origin [1] => 47293 [2] => 36586 [3] => 60426 [4] =>
>   48488 [5] => Dest )  UID: 47293 | UID2: 47293
>
> wpArray: Array ( [0] => 33.735064, -97.143939 )  1

(It is supposed to ignore the Origin and Dest points, I only want the waypoints in the array)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I changed my loop to this (hacked together hodgepodge) to get it to work... im sure there is a better way...

```
for($i=0; $i <= (count($apRow) + 1); $i++)
        {
            if ($apRow['UID'] == $optRoute[$i])
            {
                echo("<br/>UID: " . $apRow['UID'] . " | UID2: " . $optRoute[$i] . "<br/>");
                $wpCoor = $apRow['Y'] . ", " . $apRow['X'];
                $wpArray[] = $wpCoor;
            }
        }
```

which returns:

> Array ( [0] => Origin [1] => 47293 [2] => 36586 [3] => 60426 [4] =>
>   48488 [5] => Dest )
>   UID: 36586 | UID2: 36586
>
> UID: 47293 | UID2: 47293
>
> UID: 48488 | UID2: 48488
>
> UID: 60426 | UID2: 60426
>
> wpArray: Array ( [0] => 35.3214, -94.4414 [1] => 33.735064, -97.143939
>   [2] => 38.1404534, -85.737987 [3] => 38.8604916, -90.1018053 )

Comment: if you print_r $AllPoints->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) what do you get. Maybe there is an error with your query

Comment: If I change the $i to any number between 0 and 5 it returns the correct coordinates. It just seems to stop after it gets the first.

Comment: what if you did for($i = 1; $i <= count($apRow['UID']); $i++) instead of your current....

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Could you post the result of `$apRow = $AllPoints->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: the AllPoints query returns 459 items, I only want the 4 that match the $optRoute array

Comment: is your $optRoute an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
        $AllPoints = $pdo->prepare($sqlAllPoints);
        $AllPoints->execute();
        $wpArray = array();
        $i = 1;
        $apData = $AllPoints->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        foreach ($apData as $apRow)
        {
            foreach($optRoute as $optR)
            {
                if ($optR == $apRow['UID']){
                    echo("<br/>UID: " . $apRow['UID'] . " | UID2: " . $optR . "<br/>");
                    $wpCoor = $apRow['Y'] . ", " . $apRow['X'];
                    array_push($wpArray,$wpCoor);
                }
            }
        }

        echo("<br/> wpArray: ");
        print_r($wpArray);
        echo("<br/>" . $i);
    ?>
```

Comment: I still get the same result with this method :-(

Comment: might have to fetchAll() instead of PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.

Comment: No problem. I like the foreach better than the for or the while... I think it gives you better control when you have to look through something.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop expression (loop stopping condition) is always `TRUE`, that's why the loop only interates over one row.

```
$apRow['UID'] == $optRoute[$i]
// from YOUR output: UID: 47293 | UID2: 47293
// TRUE == TRUE
```

=> stop loop.

Comment: I tried with 'IF' instead of 'FOR' and I had the same thing. How do I get it to continue the loop through all 459 items?